# using xargs multiple times in one command in linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to write a one liner and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to use the following command:

```
cat testadds | cut -f 1 -d "," | xargs -ifoo /bin/bash -c "cat testadds | cut -f 2 -d \",\" | xargs --replace=addr /bin/bash -c \"cat testadds | cut -f 3 -d \",\" | xargs --replace=num /bin/bash -c \"cat testmdl | sed 's/DUMMY/foo/g' | sed 's/IP1/addr/g' | sed 's/IP2/num/g'\"\""
```

I get nothing for an out put, my `testadds` file is set up as follows:

```
dev,IP1,IP2
```

when I do this with only 2 `xargs`, it works fine, but when I add the 3rd and last `xargs`, it provides no output.  I am wondering if there is a limit to how many times you can use `xargs` when cating a file.

I guess the expected input is from a file that has multiple devices. the input would be testdevice,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2

The exepected output would be:
-deviceSystemSoftware 'device:testdevice' '6500 7-SLOT OPTICAL SW:1021'
-deviceCname 'device:testdevice' 'PRIORITY SLA - identifier - testdevice'
-deviceDateAdded 'device:testdevice' '2017-02-24'
-deviceNotes 'device:testdevice' 'BTWB100269 - testdevice'
-hier 'nib:opr|0 group:Openreach group:TSO'
-hier 'nib:opr|0 group:Openreach group:TSO group:Ciena'
-hierUnique 'nib:opr|0 group:Openreach group:TSO group:Ciena device:testdevice'

-createEntity 'service:snmp-trap-handling{device:testdevice}CA|0[+opr-ciena-6500-alarms|+Nocol]'
-createEntity 'service:configuration-tracking{device:testdevice}opr|0[ciena6500]'

-createEntity 'interface:testdevice|COLAN-1-X'
-entityDescription 'interface:testdevice|COLAN-1-X' 'COLAN-1-X'
-createEntity 'address:testdevice|COLAN-1-X|1.1.1.1'
-devicePrimaryInterface 'device:testdevice' 'interface:testdevice|COLAN-1-X'
-deleteEntity 'address:testdevice|mgmt|1.1.1.1'
-deleteEntity 'service:ippingmon{interface:testdevice|mgmt}opr|0[]'
-deleteEntity 'interface:testdevice|mgmt'
-createEntity 'interface:testdevice|SHELFIP'
-entityDescription 'interface:testdevice|SHELFIP' 'SHELFIP'
-createEntity 'address:testdevice|SHELFIP|2.2.2.2'

Hopefully this helps

What I am trying to accomplish is to modify the files to display them as the expected output.  This is to add it to my monitoring system.  Sorry, this is the first time I have ever done this, so I apologize for any lack of information.

Comment: Is there a reason your command:
1. has 3 levels of nested xargs invocations
2. doesn't seem to do anything with its arguments, making the use of xargs questionable?

Please show us your expected output.

Comment: Ah, now I see why-- you want to do multiple replacements. But you really do need to show us your entire input and expected outputs.

Comment: I guess the expected input is from a file that has multiple devices.  
the input would be testdevice,testIP1,testIP2

Comment: The exepected output would be:

-createEntity 'address:testdevice|COLAN-1-X|testIP1'
-devicePrimaryInterface 'device:testdevice' 'interface:DUMMY|COLAN-1-X'
-entityDescription 'interface:testdevice|SHELFIP' 'SHELFIP'
-createEntity 'address:testdevice|SHELFIP|testIP2'

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Every time you add a level of nesting, you need to add another level of escaping to the quotes, because one layer of quotes is going to be stripped by each call to `bash`. What exactly are you trying to *do*? (And put the expected input/output in the question itself, not jammed into a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a single `while` loop, which even on one line is shorter than your attempt (and *far* less expensive, since there are no external programs started; everything is done by built-in commands):

```
# while IFS=, read -r dev ip1 ip2; do printf "-createEntity 'address:%s|%s|%s'\n" "$dev" COLAN-1-X "$ip1" "$dev" SHELFIP "$ip2"; done < input.txt
while IFS=, read -r dev ip1 ip2; do
  printf "-createEntity 'address:%s|%s|%s'\n" \
    "$dev" COLAN-1-X "$ip1" \
    "$dev" SHELFIP "$ip2"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: I added some more lines, I did not add them before.  Sorry, I take it the input.txt would essentially be the testadds file I have the information housed in?  Thanks for all your help, sorry for my newbie mistakes

Comment: You are using the printf feature that it will process again wwhen parameters are left after processing the format string. Nice to know for @PatrickMathieus (or use a second printf just for readability).